# C++ Class - Verify a parameter before passing it to a member object

Tags: c++

I want to write a class (**Class2**) that uses another class (**Class1**).

- **Class1** requires 2 parameters (the 2nd parameter is always the same so no need to talk about it).
- **Class2** require 1 parameter, and I want to check this parameter if its valid before passing it to an object created from **Class1**

So my code looks like this :

```
class Class1
{
public:
    Class1(const string & filename, some_other_parameters);
    ...
};

class Class2
{
    Class1 C1;
public:
    Class2(const string & filename) // I want to verify this filename before passing it to C1 object
};

Class2::Class2(const string & filename)
: C1(filename, some_other_parameters){

}



int main()
{
    Class2 myClass("file.txt");
}
```

So is there a way to check the **filename** before passing it to **C1** or should I do it in the **main()** ?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the filename is not valid?

Comment: You could check it in the body of the constructor if you find it acceptable to throw an exception on failure.

Comment: What do you mean by "valid" - the file exists, or something else?

Comment: Ask yourself which part actually requires that the filename is some kind of "valid"? If it's `Class1`, let that class do the validation. If `Class2` imposes some additional constraints, you could use Martin's solution. If `Class2` is the only one that requires it, you can forward it to `Class1` and perform the check in the constructor body. If neither of them actually requires it, I wonder where the code is that actually does...

Comment: @ChrisDrewqsd : If the file doesn't exist or not valid (call a member function to check it) so it creates a new one

Comment: That's introducing a race condition. Nothing guarantees that between checking if the file is there and opening the file nobody deleted the file or created one in place. A much better approach is to just open the file and handle failures accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just used a pointer for Class1

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

class Class1
{
public:
    Class1(const std::string & filename, int a)
    {
        // ...
    }
};

class Class2
{
    Class1 * p_C1;
public:
    Class2(const std::string & filename)
    {
        // ------------------------------------
        // Check the file before p_C1 creation
        // ------------------------------------
        p_C1 = new Class1(filename, 1);
    }
    ~Class2(void)
    {
        if (p_C1 != NULL) delete p_C1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Class2 myClass("file.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just invoke a static function to do the validation, but otherwise forward it's argument:

```
class Class2
{
    Class1 C1;
    static const std::string& validate_filename(const std::string& filename);
public:
    Class2(const string & filename)
};

const std::string& Class2::validate_filename(const std::string& filename)
{
   if (filename.size() < 2)
      throw std::runtime_error("filename too short");
   return filename;
}

Class2::Class2(const string & filename)
: C1(validate_filename(filename), some_other_parameters){
}
```

Note that you can use a similar technique if you want to transform the argument.  So you can convert from wide char to utf8 and force the path to be in a canonical format, ... and still have the member variable be const.

You should also consider which class should be responsible for the validation.  If C1 has constraints on its arguments, then it should check them.  If on the other hand it would be fine with any string, but C2 has constraints, then it must do the checking.

Comment: well its a good idea to pass **validate_filename(filename)** as a parameter, I wonder why I didn't think about it. Thanks Martin you saved my day.